# Logic Error Cleaning up Empty Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a number of tables in my document all under the class `table.grid`.  I'm trying to go through and delete any table headers with no `<td>` fields, i.e. empty tables / tables that were generated with no results.  The heirarchy for the table classes for the header is `table.grid tbody tr.header th` and the td's are subsequently `table.grid tbody tr td`  . Currently my code is as follows:

```
$('table.grid tbody tr.header th').each(function (i) {
    var remove = 0;
    var tds = $(this).parents('tbody').find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');

    tds.each(function (j) {
        if (this.innerHTML == '') remove++;
    });

    if (remove == ($('table.grid tbody tr td').length - 1)) {
        $(this).hide();
        tds.hide();
    }
});
```

But unfortunately, this is deleting EVERY table header.  Not just the ones with no content.  I believe I'm calling the `td` field incorrectly with my if statement, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  I've attempted calling it as `$(this).next('table.grid tbody tr td').length - 1)` and have also tried the `closest()` operator to no avail.

Comment: There's an easier way to decide when to remove a row.  Set `var remove = true;`.  Inside tds.each() if `this.innerHTML != ''` set remove to false.  Afterwards, if `remove` is true, hide the row.  Beats tallying up the empty cells and comparing that to the number of cells in the row.

Comment: Could you please show us a brief example of a table with a row to remove?  It would help me check your selectors.

Comment: Sure.  Sorry for being too unspecific.  Check out this jsfiddle for an example of two of the section tables.  The first table would be kept since it has results, but I'm looking to purge the entire empty second table because no results were compounded when the document was made. http://jsfiddle.net/sM3Uc/1/  If you need any more information or I accidentally omitted something just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your exact requirement to hide a table.  I am going under the assumption that an "empty" table has only 1 row in it with header info.  Any other rows would have content, making that table non-empty.  I decided to leverage this and check for the number of non-header rows:

```
$('table.grid').each(function (i) {
    //Select all rows in this table that aren't .header
    var rows = $(this).find("tr").not(".header");

    if (rows.length == 0)
    {
        //no rows except for header - hide the table.
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

You can see this in a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sM3Uc/4/), using the HTML you provided.  It's hiding the second table because it has no rows beyond the headers.

Just a note... if you control the server side of this application, your absolute best strategy is to detect an empty result set and skip it so you don't have to clean it up later.  You may not have that as an option, so this may help you handle it in the browser instead.

Please do let me know if I misunderstood your needs for what to hide and when.

Comment: That's actually perfect.  You're right though, unfortunately I have absolutely no access to server-side anything.  Just patching some disgusting visual messes :(